# How to insert an element into a vector?

Tags: matlab

In MATLAB I have a vector with size 1-by-3. Now I need to insert an element to this vector but sometimes

this number must be first element of this vector, sometimes second and so on.

Does anyone know how I could do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague, but if you mean you need to insert a new element into an existing vector, here's how it can be done:

```
>> insertAfter = 1; % insert element after first
>> newVec = cat(2, v(1:insertAfter), newElement, v( (insertAfter+1):end ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

Insert element `I` to vector `V` at location `N`

```
V = [V(1:N-1) I V(N:end)]
```

Test

```
V = zeros(1,3);
I = 1;
N = 2;
V = [V(1:N-1) I V(N:end)]

V =

   0   1   0   0
```

Answer (score 2):

There are more than a few ways to do this, so you'll just have to take your pick.  Here's one that I would prefer for in-place insertion of the scalar `newEl` at location `ii` of vector `v`:

```
v(ii:end+1) = [newEl v(ii:end)];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
clear all
clc

v1 = [ 3 2 8 9 ] % The first vector
q=length(v1) % The length of the first vector
v2=1:q+1 % Creating a new vector with length old + 1
v2(1:q)=v1 % Changing the first part of the vector to the old (v1) vector

v1=v2 % To go back to the same name of the first vector
```